# Unexpected char 0x645 at 744 in token value

Tags: kotlin, utf-8, retrofit, moshi

I sent a retrofit rest api and convert response with moshi to kotlin data class, because of response has utf-8 character, it can't convert to data class and crash.

Unexpected char 0x645 at 744 in token value: GcfiTp8ghpm6iqeRPzJpaNyw,name=علی رضایی

I know I need to add UTF-8 encoding somewhere, but I do not know where can I add it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869988/unexpected-char-0x662-at-42-in-content-disposition-value-form-data-name-userf

Comment: that question is about body not about response.

Comment: I just gave you the idea. Post your code as well.

Comment: I change retrofit converter from moshi to gson, my problem vanished. thank you.